# organize MongoDB document to manipulate the data better

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would need help making a data structure with mongodb.
I'm using JavaScript to manipulate data.
I would like to have a document structure of this type, but i'm not sure to do the right thing. I noticed that you tend to use the array also as a container of objects, and i also noticed that the mongodb update operators need a structure of this type. for example:

```
var mydoc = {
               _id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
               items:[ {"name": "name", "other": "other"},
                       {"name": "name", "other": "other"},
                       {"name": "name", "other": "other"}
                     ]}
```

but organize data in this way do not like :) how i would like the document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "dfdsdsfdsff54sdf5ds"
  },
  "displayName": "name",
  "userId": "h8566d9482gghffhtry565",
  "info": {
    "level": 1,
    "currentExperience": 0,
    "requiredExperience": 0,
    "missingExperience": 0
  },
  "statistics": {
    "total": {
      "stat1": 0,
      "stat2": 0,
      "stat3": 0,
      "stat4": 0
    },
    "best": {
      "distance": 0,
      "stat1": 0,
      "stat2": 0,
      "stat3": 0,
      "stat4": 0
    },
    "game": {
      "one": 0,
      "two": 0,
      "three": 0,
      "stat4": 0
    }
  },
  "inventory": {
    "item1": {
      "property1": 0,
      "property2": 0,
      "property3": 0,
      "property4": 0,
      "level": {
        "level": 1,
        "currentExperience": 0,
        "requiredExperience": 0,
        "missingExperience": 0
      },
      "skins": [
        "skin1",
        "skin2",
        "skin3"
      ]
    },
    "item2": {
      "property1": 0,
      "property2": 0,
      "property3": 0,
      "property4": 0,
      "level": {
        "level": 1,
        "currentExperience": 0,
        "requiredExperience": 0,
        "missingExperience": 0
      },
      "skins": [
        "skin1",
        "skin2",
        "skin3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notifications": {},
  "rewards": {}
}
```

Now i explain what the problems im having.
now if i have to change, for example, a property of a specific item that is inside inventory, i take the object "inventory" -> i look for the item i need and then i modify the property.
at the end of this, using an update operator "$set", i replace the "inventory" field.

This may be fine if you have very little data, but within that field there will be hundreds of "sub-field" and this seems like a useless waste resources.

Unfortunately, using $inc operator, i can not pass in any way "the path" of the property that i want to change.
could you help me?

here is what i do now

```
var userDoc = myCollection("userData");
var userData = userDoc.findOne({"userId": userId}, {items: 1, _id: 0});
//Other code
userData.inventory[itemName][propertyName] = //other code;
userDoc.update({"userId": userId},{"$set": userData});
```

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update an embedded document, you can access it using dot notation.

For above document, to update "property1" of "item1" inside "inventory":

```
db.inventory.update({"userId":"h8566d9482gghffhtry565"},{"$set":{"inventory.item1.property1":"1"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the "path" is dynamic, I do not know which item will be modified. is the user decide which properties of the items change, I found this solution:

```
var inc = {$inc: {}};
inc.$inc['inventory.'+itemName+"."+statName] = 1; // itemName and statName are variables created by  user

userDoc.update({"userId": userId}, inc);
```